# Async vs non-async version with same name not distinguished by compiler

Tags: ios, swift

I have two functions that do the same thing. One has an optional completion block the other is async:

```
  @MainActor
  @objc static func dismiss(_ completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    
  }

  @MainActor
  @objc static func dismiss() async {
    
  }
```

When I call these functions from another @MainActor function, the compiler can't seem to distinguish between the async vs non-async version:

```
@MainActor
static func myFunc() async {
  await dismiss() // works
  dismiss() // Error: "Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'"
  dismiss(nil) // works
}
```

When in reality, calling `dismiss()` should work because the compiler should be able to detect there's a non-async version of a function with that name. Why doesn't this work? Is the only way to get around this to specify `nil` as in the last example?

Comment: Remove @MainActor then it will work.

Comment: @MainActor is that it automatically forces methods or whole types to run on the main actor, a lot of the time without any further work from us. Previously we needed to do it by hand, remembering to use code like DispatchQueue.main.async() or similar every place it was needed, but now the compiler does it for us automatically.

Comment: A function can't both be @MainActor and non-async

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention – I'm calling `dismiss()` from another function which is also a @MainActor. Shouldn't that negate the need for await?

Comment: Have updated my sample code to reflect this

Comment: I'm wondering whether a Swift `async` function can be exposed to `ObjC` st all…

Comment: @vadian It doesn't complain about that... but I will check

Comment: @vadian turns out it can, objc automatically converts it to a completion block. Anyway, that's off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is by design. Since you have named both the function the same, Swift assumes both the method do the same thing and depending on the context of the invoker the actual method is chosen.

Since your `myFunc` function is asynchronous swift prefers the async version of `dismiss` and if you make `myFunc` synchronous `dismiss` with completion handler will be preferred. Although, in my opinion, this should be a warning rather than an error.

Now suppose your synchronous `dismiss` function does some long calculation that shouldn't be done on `MainActor`. Now if for example your current code is accepted by the compiler, it would cause stutter in your app at runtime. Swift is indicating here to choose the async `dismiss` instead so that your complex work will run on background freeing `MainActor` to process other tasks.